# Why are things that I mark as duplicate immediately reopened?

Tags: discussion

I marked a Python question as a duplicate. Since I have the gold tag in Python, this is usually the end of it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127177/can-i-flatten-a-list-using-recursive-function-and-list-comprehension?noredirect=1) was reopened without comment from a machine process or moderator within *seconds* of me closing it. Another commenter agreed that it was a duplicate.

Can I understand why? This is the second time this has happened, and it is discouraging.

Comment: Why do you ask the question like it happens to you repeatedly? It only happened this one time apparently.

Comment: It has happened before. The other time, I was the fifth vote of the question as a duplicate (so gold status was irrelevant). All answers were being downvoteed. I cannot find that question so I did not link to it.

Comment: Darn, its even right there in the text. I totally read over it.

Answer (score 10):

The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50127177/revisions) says it was [this other badger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750492/achampion). The other badger also explained their reasons in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127177/can-i-flatten-a-list-using-recursive-function-and-list-comprehension#comment87272392_50127177). Also, it wasn't reopened in seconds; it took about 4 minutes 20 seconds before the other badger reopened the question.

It doesn't look like there's anything weird going on. Someone just disagreed with you.

See [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865) for the details about how gold-tag-badge dupe closing and reopening is implemented.

Comment: So someone else of similar badging can reopen a duplicate? Just trying to learn here...

Comment: (seemed like seconds to ME ;-)

Comment: @dawg: Yes, the dupehammer is also an *un*dupehammer.

Comment: @dawg yes provided they have the gold badge in a tag set in the post

Comment: The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50127177/timeline) shows that there were relevant comments too.

Comment: That is just 260 seconds.